# Изменить название view в Android

Tags: java, android

Есть такое создание ProgressBar

```
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mainLayout.addView(progressBar);
```

Но таких баров у меня будет несколько, и мне надо с ними взаимодействовать в разное время(сразу было бы проще). Но этим способом получается же так, что они все создаются с одинаковыми именами, и я вот не знаю как обращаться к каждому из них. Как можно изменять при создании имя "progressBar" с первой строки ?
P.S: Я не знаю сколько их будет каждый раз, в этом и сложность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать List и работать с элементами листа как с отдельными View элементами

```
    List<ProgressBar> progressBarList = new ArrayList<>();

    ProgressBar progressBar1 = new ProgressBar(this);
    ProgressBar progressBar2 = new ProgressBar(this);
    ...
    ProgressBar progressBarN = new ProgressBar(this);

    progressBarList.add(progressBar1);
    progressBarList.add(progressBar2);
    ...
    progressBarList.add(progressBarN);


    progressBarList.get(0);
    progressBarList.get(1);
    ...
    progressBarList.get(N);

    progressBarList.get(0).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mainLayout.addView(progressBarList.get(0));
```

Comment: Тут только последующие создания других баров лишние, так как теперь работать нужно лишь с их номерами с листа, а так мне это подходит, спасибо